# Adding audio file to my android application

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I want to add .mp3 file and I don't have res/row folder in my eclipse  and I tried to add it but it doesn't appear in R.java

Comment: Try this [Tutorial](http://lecturesnippets.com/android-playing-sound-mediaplayer/)

Answer (score 1):

you have to create raw folder manually in the following path. res/raw/yourfile.mp3. Then clean and Build your project. Now you will get the reference to that mp3 by R.raw.yourfile;

kindly let me know the feedback.

Answer (score 0):

Just right click on your res folder and add a new folder by the name of 'raw'. Here copy and paste your .mp3 file. Make sure that the name of your file is totally lower case as it creates problem later. 
Just clean your project and build it again. You will find your file there.

Answer (score 0):

Try using raw instead of row. it will create in R.java
[image]

Answer (score 0):

create a raw folder in res. paste the mp3 file in this and use path code as follows

String uriPath = "android.resource://Package name/"+ R.raw.MP3file;

I hope you get help from this.

If you face again problem then comment